# populate tableview based on returned queryEqual(toValue)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, parent-child, children

I am having trouble populating a tableView based on snapshot keys. The console is printing all (nodeToReturn) values from the parent node and children that are called from the queryEqual(toValue: locationString), so I know I am querying them correctly. But for some reason my tableView keeps populating all the User dictionaries from my Database.database().reference().child("Travel_Experience_Places"). I just want the tableView to display the snapshot data from the "nodeToReturn" values, so not every parent node from my "Travel_Experience_Places" database reference - only the parent nodes that have the same value of "locationString" in its children. Hopefully that makes sense. Thanks in advance!

// model object

```
class User: SafeUserObject {

    var id: String?
    var name: String?
    var email: String?
    var profileImageUrl: String?
    var place: String?

    init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
        super.init()

        self.id = dictionary["fromId"] as? String
        self.name = dictionary["addedBy"] as? String
        self.email = dictionary["email"] as? String
        self.profileImageUrl = dictionary["profileImageUrl"] as? String
        self.place = dictionary["place"] as? String
        setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
    }
}
```

// JSON structure

```
  "Travel_Experience_Places" : {
    "-Ks0Ms4fEQZxBytI-vu_" : {
      "addedBy" : "Daniel Meier",
      "place" : "Barcelona, Spain",
      "profileImageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/travelapp-255da.appspot.com/o/profile_images%2F21673E85-4F58-480D-B0A9-65884CADF7B3.png?alt=media&token=9e111014-d1d7-4b3b-a8c2-3897032c34cc",
      "timestamp" : 1.503261589872372E9
    },
```

// tableview to return firebase queryEqual(toValue: locationString) in tableview

```
var experiencePlaceUsers = [User]()

    func fetchTravelingUserCell() {

        let databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("Travel_Experience_Places")
        databaseRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "place").queryEqual(toValue: locationString).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

            if snapshot.exists(){
                let allKeys = snapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject]
                let nodeToReturn = allKeys.keys
                print(nodeToReturn) // prints parent and child values that have locationString as a child value in its data structure
            }
        })

        databaseRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                let user = User(dictionary: dictionary)
                self.experiencePlaceUsers.append(user)

                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }, withCancel: nil)
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return experiencePlaceUsers.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! UserCell
    cell.user = experiencePlaceUsers[indexPath.item]

    return cell
}
```

Comment: It would help if you could have an example of Firebase JSON. Also, noticed something; not sure what you mean by the comment :"this will crash because of background thread". I have never had to use async to reload my table.

Comment: Can you please show the code for tableview?

Comment: nodeToReturn are users?

Comment: nodeToReturn is the snapshot returning all the values inside the "place" firebase node.

Comment: can you show the output of print(nodeToReturn)

Comment: So allKeys and dictionary in above code , both represent users but allKeys represent filtered? am I right?

Comment: below is nodeToReturn
LazyMapCollection<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, String>(_base: ["-Ks0nLz4nHqjZdpF8LRt": {
    addedBy = Jbroyles;
    place = "Kailua-Kona, HI, USA";
    profileImageUrl = "the imageUrl here...";
    timestamp = "1503268794.325255";
}], _transform: (Function))

Comment: allKeys is the snapshot from the queryEqual(toValue: locationString)... so yes I believe allKeys is a filtered list of users that share the same locationString value in their children "place:"

Comment: Currently the tableview returns all Users and their dictionary items (profileImageUrl, addedBy, etc...) fine, but I would like to return User object with related dictionary items, BUT only the Users that have the value of "locationString" inside their children "place:". So in my comment example above I want to return all users that share the "Place: Kailua-Kona, HI, USA".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to reload the tableview in your block where you get nodeToReurn

```
var experiencePlaceUsers = [User]()

    func fetchTravelingUserCell() {



    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("Travel_Experience_Places")
                databaseRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "place").queryEqual(toValue: locationString).observe(. childAdded, with: { snapshot in



                if snapshot.exists(){
                    if let allKeys = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        let singleUser = User(dictionary: allKeys)
                        self.experiencePlaceUsers.append(singleUser)


                        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                           self.tableView.reloadData()
                        })
                   }
                }
            }) 


   /*
        databaseRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                let user = User(dictionary: dictionary)
                self.experiencePlaceUsers.append(user)

                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }, withCancel: nil)
*/
    }
```

Comment: no luck...just returned empty cell with no dictionary values

Comment: logic makes sense, I believe I have tried that. I think I provided all related code but let me know if you think there may be something else I should include. Thanks for the time

Comment: @user3708224 please add print(allKeys) before let singleUser = User(dictionary: allKeys) and see what it prints, and please comment the code below for all users for now

Comment: so it looks like it is printing the same values as it was before so the all keys is still returning the same value. It prints this - ["-Ks0nLz4nHqjZdpF8LRt": {
    addedBy = Jbroyles;
    place = "Kailua-Kona, HI, USA";
    profileImageUrl = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/travelapp-255da.appspot.com/o/profile_images%2FD4F4EA7F-79E9-4EAB-9D7E-39CA7D6D7638.png?alt=media&token=0d6b214c-7ed1-4673-a80b-56e0f8997ac1";
    timestamp = "1503268794.325255";
}]

Comment: @user3708224 tableview is still not loading the filtered data?

Comment: nope... it just returns one empty cell...hmmmm?? The only difference that I am noticing in the 2 snapshots is .childAdded vs queryEqual(toValue: locationString). Not sure that has anything to do with populating the tableView

Comment: @user3708224 ok good, lets do some more debugging, please add print(self.experiencePlaceUsers) after self.experiencePlaceUsers.append(singleUser) and see what it prints

Comment: ok, so its not printing anything for singleUser or self.experiencePlaceUsers (not even a nil value)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152484/discussion-between-user1000-and-user3708224).